# Context array in api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

Why does api.ai have context array, that creates contexts with some arbitrary names which live until the intent is complete?

When the intent is complete if a context is created it is retained rest others are removed, what is the significance of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to cases when you are in the middle of resolving an intent, you get context names that look like this: `72e79993-...-10dc7db59a93_id_dialog_context`

This is happening because the intent has not yet been resolved, and the system creates a sort of temporary, interim context for any exchanges happening in this middle point, before the intent is resolved and export contexts are triggered.

In the cases you see it, you'll probably notice they're when the user has not filled in a required parameter values and API.ai has to respond with a prompt for the user to input their desired value. This 'prompt response' is a response but not a resolution of the intent. So to store/mark this temporary state as being different from a full response and resolved intent state (and to help interpret what the user says in this hyper-specific context of clarifying a specific parameter value given a specific intent), API.ai inserts these 'hyper-specific' interim context names.

You'll notice the context names in these cases match the metadata's intentID, for this very reason.